# Opening a file with full network name changes sheet names

Tags: excel, vba

It's a pretty short question, but nowhere else online seems to know the answer.

When I do this:

```
Workbooks.Open ("Y:\ME\Trends.xlsm")
```

All is fine, and everything works, however, when I do this:

```
Workbooks.Open("\\*full network name*\ME\Trends.xlsm")
```

The chart names change. The workbook is essentially 10 charts, each with a different name. When opening with the full network name, it still opens, but the sheet names become "Chart 1", "Chart 2", etc. Is there a fix to that?

Comment: you need to find what is causing it to behave that way first if you want to fix anything. What do You think is causing it because opening it from the network location may not necessarily be the cause. Is it a trusted location? Are macros enables? Is there any Auto_Open or Workbook_Open event code?

Comment: It is both trusted and macros are enabled. I ran this on an auto open from another workbook, and this is the only line i have in it. So essentially, that one line is my entire code, just with `Sub Auto_Open` and `End Sub` around it. So, to the extent of my seeing, if that is the only line and the error only occurs when I take out `Y:`, this is the only source of error from the VBA standpoint, unless there are default options that could hinder this.

Comment: Try to copy you path in Run (Windows + R) and test if it opens.

Comment: @Makah it opens, however it DOES give the same error of changing all the sheet names. So it could be a network restriction rather than a coding error..

Comment: And if you open the file from Run with the Drive letter it opens correctly?

Comment: @user2140261 Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to recreate this issue but its possible the below alternative method to open a workbook may be of some help.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub OpenTest()
Dim objXL As Object
Dim oShell As Object
Dim strExcel As String
Dim WBPath As String

strExcel = Chr(34) & "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE" & Chr(34) & " /e "

WBPath = "\\*full network name*\ME\Trends.xlsm"

Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objXL = Nothing
oShell.Exec (strExcel & Chr(34) & WBPath & Chr(34))
Sleep 2000
Set objXL = GetObject(WBPath).Application
objXL.Application.Goto objXL.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), True
Set objXL = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @B Hart Nice! Again, I'm assuming it's just my personal network error, not in the code, but this worked perfectly. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Sidenote my office folder is `\Office14` not 12 if anyone else looks at this, that's all I had to change (along with the network name).

Comment: @JoeLaviano - I'm happy to hear its working for you.  I appreciate the follow up :)